# "Self-study" vs "self-education"

Tags: expressions

I got a book titled *Self-study vocabulary practice*. Can I replace *self-study* with *self-education*?

Does it make sense to use *self-learning* in the statement of above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some examples that you might find useful:

1. I am educating myself
2. I am an autodidact
3. Self-study often leads to rapid but shallow knowledge acquisition
4. While trying to *educate myself* about the benefits of *self-study*, I found that "self-education" and "self-learning" are short-circuited and incorrect terms.

In summary: Self-study is the acceptable term; the other choices that you mention are probably not what you want to use.

Comment: If you are going to suggest a word like *autodidact*, it is probably important to mention that almost nobody will recognize the word or know what it means.

Comment: @Kosmonaut: I agree with what you say, though I note for the interested few, that speakers of German might easily understand what *autodidact* means (I have often heard some of them use *Autodidakt*).

Answer (score 2):

*Self-study* is the standard word to use here, not *self-education* or *self-learning*. Also, *education* usually refers to something broader or more long-term.